# How to get the second to last directory in a path string in C#

Tags: c#, string, path, directory

For example,

```
string path = @"C:\User\Desktop\Drop\images\";
```

I need to get only `@"C:\User\Desktop\Drop\`

Is there any easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `Path` and `Directory` classes:

```
DirectoryInfo parentDir = Directory.GetParent(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
string parent = parentDir.FullName;
```

Note that you would get a different result if the path doesn't end with the directory-separator char `\`. Then `images` would be understood as filename and not as directory.

You can also use  a subsequent call of `Path.GetDirectoryName`

```
string parent = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
```

This behaviour is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx):

> Because the returned path does not include the DirectorySeparatorChar
>   or AltDirectorySeparatorChar, **passing the returned path back into the
>   GetDirectoryName method will result in the truncation of one folder
>   level per subsequent call on the result string.** For example, passing
>   the path "C:\Directory\SubDirectory\test.txt" into the
>   GetDirectoryName method will return "C:\Directory\SubDirectory".
>   Passing that string, "C:\Directory\SubDirectory", into
>   GetDirectoryName will result in "C:\Directory".

Comment: +1 for the only solution with `Directory.GetParent`, much safer and better approach rather than string operations

Comment: in given example this   Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)) will return required result, depending whatever the trailing slash is present it GetDirectoryName will return current or parent level

Comment: As long as ppl are aware of different results from GetDirectoryName this should cover the question - upvoted. For more complex scenario i added my own answer with trailing slash check

Answer (score 1):

This will return "C:\User\Desktop\Drop\" e.g. everything but the last subdir

```
string path = @"C:\User\Desktop\Drop\images";
string sub = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
```

Another solution if you have a trailing slash:

```
string path = @"C:\User\Desktop\Drop\images\";
var splitedPath = path.Split('\\');
var output = String.Join(@"\", splitedPath.Take(splitedPath.Length - 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var parent = ""; 
If(path.EndsWith(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) || path.EndsWith(System.IO.Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar))
{
  parent = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
  parent = Directory.GetParent(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)).FullName;
}
else
  parent = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

As i commented GetDirectoryName is self collapsing it returns path without tralling slash - allowing to get next directory.Using Directory.GetParent for then clouse is also valid.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer :)

```
path = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(path)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Example on the bottom of the page probably will help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace Programs
{
    public class Program
    {      
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputText = @"C:\User\Desktop\Drop\images\";
            Console.WriteLine(inputText.Substring(0, 21));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> C:\User\Desktop\Drop\

Comment: Nope but isn't a solution in this case? We don't have other information include that.

Comment: In **one, very specific** case --- but when has writing good software ever been about hard-coding to one problem at a time?

Comment: Of course. You are right, but when I looking the question, my answer look a good ones. Of course the question isn't good, but my answer is a solution for the asker side. But of course I say again, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some simple way to do this using the File or Path classes, but you could also solve it by doing something like this (Note: not tested):

```
string fullPath = "C:\User\Desktop\Drop\images\";
string[] allDirs = fullPath.split(System.IO.Path.PathSeparator);

string lastDir = allDirs[(allDirs.length - 1)];
string secondToLastDir= allDirs[(allDirs.length - 2)];
// etc...
```